# IFR Currency with a safety pilot who has a BasicMed

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, basicmed, safety-pilot

Here’s my situation and question.  For my IFR currency, I’ve asked a friend to be the Safety Pilot.  He’s aptly qualified BUT he does not have the traditional Medical, but rather he has BasicMed.  My question is; Can I still use him as a Safety Pilot, without jeopardizing my IFR Currency?  If he’s deemed PIC, can I still claim the time and use the IFR work (approaches, hold, tracking, etc…) for my IFR currency?

Comment: Due to a quirk in the Basic Med rules, he can only act as a safety pilot if he is PIC—which is fine. Logging time doesn’t depend on being PIC, only on being the sole manipulator of the controls.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42989/how-does-the-faa-basicmed-affect-the-safety-pilot-for-somebody-flying-under-the

Answer (score 1):

FAR 61.113(i) authorizes flight as PIC when using BasicMed. Therefore, your buddy can act as safety pilot if he is also acting as PIC.

If you were acting as PIC, that would make your buddy SIC (as a required crew member), which still requires a traditional medical certificate.

Comment: He can be PIC but not SIC???

Comment: @DJClayworth Correct. BasicMed only allows flying as PIC, not SIC, as strange as that seems. Laws are not required to make sense.