# Does a safety pilot for a PPL practicing under the hood in VFR conditions need a current medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, vmc

Am I legal to fly under the hood with a safety pilot who does not have a current medical? VMC only, not IMC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [AC 68-1A](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_68-1A.pdf), a safety pilot requires a current medical:

> A pilot acting as a safety pilot per part 91, § 91.109(c), however,
>   would be a required pilot flightcrew member by regulation rather than
>   a passenger. Section 91.109(c) provides that no person may operate a
>   civil aircraft in simulated instrument flight unless the other control
>   seat is occupied by a safety pilot who possesses at least a private
>   pilot certificate with category and class ratings appropriate to the
>   aircraft being flown. Because a safety pilot is a required pilot
>   flightcrew member, the safety pilot is required to hold a valid and
>   appropriate medical certificate in accordance with § 61.3(a).

For information on a safety pilot using BasicMed see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42989/62).

By the way, by definition a safety pilot is only required in VMC. In IMC you're in actual instrument conditions; see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39518/62).

Comment: Thank you, especially the FAR reference.