# How do I maximize flight hour usage in getting an instrument rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-rating

I recently finished a private pilot certificate and I'd like to get a instrument rating while keeping my costs low.  I understand I'll need 50 hours of cross country PIC time (VFR) and 40 hours instrument training.

Question:  If I fly under the hood with a Safety Pilot on cross country flights for 15 hours, do those 15 hours count both towards the 50 hours of cross country PIC time and towards the 40 hours of instrument training time?

Here is the breakdown of what I think I would need:

50 hours cross country PIC time consisting of:
15 hours cross country PIC time I already have,
15 hours cross country PIC time while under the hood with a Safety Pilot, and 20 hours cross country PIC time solo (or with a friend).

40 hours instrument training, consisting of:
4 hours already completed with instructor (3 from PPL),
15 hours under hood with Safety Pilot,
10 hours with instructor in Redbird simulator,
and 11 hours with instructor in airplane.

Am I getting this right?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15586/62)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite answer my question about overlap of the 15 hours under the hood with a Safety Pilot - do those 15 hours count both towards the 50 hours of cross country PIC time and for the 40 hours of instrument training time?

Comment: I don't want to sound unhelpful but you might want to review the requirements in 61.56(d), assuming you want an airplane IR. You seem to have a couple of misunderstandings, e.g. the 40hrs is instrument time, not instruction time. If you don't understand the requirements then of course feel free to ask about them here, preferably by quoting the part you didn't get. I think that will help to make your question clearer, and to get you a better response.

Comment: I'm just wanting to know if I can double dip on hours - if I can count hood time with a Safety Pilot both for the 50 hours of cross country PIC time and for the 40 hours of instrument time.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! Although I believe that's already answered in [your other recent question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/79154/62) about using a safety pilot while logging time cross-country time.

Comment: OK, so the answer is yes.  I thought so, but I was just making sure.  That reduces the cost quite a bit.

Comment: @Pondlife either make your comment an answer, or we need to close this as a dupe.